# sql update not working dont know how to fix

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am lost here please help

my data base table will not update when I use this code

```
$sqlpassword = "UPDATE login SET password='$hashedP' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
$querypass = mysqli_query($db_x, $sqlpassword);
```

I have tried to look around maybe i'm not seeing it but im sure its right

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` say? Does it work when you run the final SQL statement (that you hopefully already printed out) from MysqlAdmin etc?

Answer (score 2):

`password` is a reserved word in MySQL. You have to wrap fieldnames in backticks so that MySQL doesn't see it as a SQL command.

```
$sqlpassword = "UPDATE `login` SET `password`='$hashedP' WHERE `id`='$id' LIMIT 1";
$querypass = mysqli_query($db_x, $sqlpassword);
```

Comment: "password" is not a reserved word => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea, I was thinking of removing this. My error came from MySQL workbench showing syntax highlighting it. So I've always assumed it was reserved.

Comment: It happenened to me in the past as well. I know many of them by heart, but when in doubt, I check the MySQL.com website, juuuuust to be 100% sure lol

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the **`LIMIT`** keyword on UPDATE Statement.

Just use

```
$sqlpassword = "UPDATE `login` SET `password`='$hashedP' WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

<sup>**Disclaimer**: Make use of **`Prepared Statements`** to avoid SQL Injection Attacks.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. You are making commit after this update statement.
2. Check why you need the `limit` keyword, else remove it.
3. Check if the `id` is a number in your table structure or string, since in this update you are dealing with it as string.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out sorry for wasting your time

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
```

was not putting in

```
edit.php?c=<?php echo $log_company ?>
```

so form was going to edit.php not edit.php?c=truestory

Comment: It's good you found the answer to your own problem but the solution you have posted shows no relationship to the information in your question. If I were you, I'd consider deleting your own question as it does not provide useful information to others coming to Stack Overflow.